# Multidimensional Array in Dart [List]

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I was trying to create a **nested list** or **multidimensional array** where a **key** may have **multiple values** and I want to access only one **particular** value of that key's values.

```
void main()
{

  var family = {"Nabi": "Delowar", "Zerin" : ["Taheem", "Ayan"], "Nipa" : "Faizan"};

  print(family['Zerin[0]']); // this doesn't work

  print(family['Zerin']); // this prints ["Taheem", "Ayan"]

}
```

I want the output of **Zerin[0]** to be **Taheem**

Answer (score 2):

First get the array from the Map with key `'Zerin'` then get the item at index `0`

```
print(family['Zerin'][0]);
```

Comment: `var dd =family['Zerin'];
  
print(dd[0]); `
  // not working
  



  // The following works

  `for(String d in dd)
    {
      print(d);
    }`

Comment: got it.
without using `var dd = ...` I need to use `List dd = ...`

Comment: It should work when you run it, it's just that static analysis can't know it's a List.

Comment: neither did i know. So, I ran `print(dd.runtimeType);` to find out

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
for (var key in family.keys) {
    print(key); // "Nabi", "Zerin", "Nipa"
}

for (var value in family.values) {
    print(value); // "Delowar", ["Taheem", "Ayan"], "Faizan"
}
```